# Removing subview from UITableView header view

Tags: uitableview, tableview, subview, autoresizingmask, nstableheaderview

My iOS apps shows a UITableView with a tableHeaderView containing 3 subviews (A,B and C).

---

### |   A    |

### |   B    |

## |   C    |

### | cell1  |

### | cell2  |

### | cell3  |

|   ...  |

The problem is that when I remove C using:

```
[C removeFromSuperview]
```

I have a white gap left that I would like to remove too in order the tableview to be attached directly to B. I tried resizing the whole tableHeaderView and tweaking the AutoresizingMask,but with no luck.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to tell the table to resize the header view. Just setting the tableHeaderView works for me

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = tableView.tableHeaderView
```